# Ошибка открытия windows раздела из под linux

Tags: linux, windows, hdd, ntfs, dual-boot

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb4 at /media/l4meeeer/Disk: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdb4" "/media/l4meeeer/Disk"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить эту ошибку, что нужно сделать? Пытаюсь на линуксе открыть  раздел Win10...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 варианта:

1. Последовать совету в ошибке и добавить ключ `ro` (read only)
2. Если это системный раздел - грузануть винду и завершить её нормально, а не через сон\гибернацию\спящий режим.

Comment: И без быстрого старта.

Answer (score 0):

Ведь написано:

```
: Operation not permitted
```

Команду mount может выдавать только суперюсер.  Поэтому делать надо так:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs  ...
```

Кстати, а зачем у Вас кавычки вокруг ntfs?