# Как перенести файл с Linux на Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, файлы, dual-boot

Linux и Windows стоят на одном диске, нужно передать файл (13 гигов) с Linux на Windows, варианты?

Comment: Windows драйвер для доступа к линуксовой файловой системе. Или посмотри, умеет ли это WSL, если у тебя десятка. А уж Линукс на НТФС просто обязан уметь копировать... Ну или использовать ФАТ32-флешку для переноса.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586120/copy-files-from-windows-to-the-ubuntu-subsystem возможно это поможет

Comment: @Akina А что делать, если с Linux раздел с виндой с read-only открывается?

Comment: *с Linux раздел с виндой с read-only открывается?* Это в Линуксе драйвер доступа RO или раздел примонтирован как RO?

Comment: @coi175 перемонтировать как read-write, очевидно :)

Comment: @Akina, 13Гб на FAT32?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Кусочками...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/879318/191416

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В люнихе ставите драйвер виндовых дисков *ntfs-3g* (если он ещё не установлен) и монтируете их. После этого копируете все файлы, какие захотите, туда и сюда с помощью обычной команды *cp*.

У меня виндовые диски монтируются через fstab, при загрузке системы:

```
# Диски Windows
/dev/sda2 /mnt/disk_c ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0
/dev/sda3 /mnt/disk_d ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0
```

Да, забыл уточнить: всё это относится к файловой системе NTFS на винде.

Answer (score 2):

Если это бинарный файл, а судя по размеру это так, то можно просто переместить. Файлы в операционных системах выглядят одинаково, имеет значение только файловая система диска. В данном случае файловая система стоит одна и та же. Если брать текстовые файлы, тогда да, тут нужна прога, которая поменяет переносы строк - windows и linux имеют разные коды переносов строк. И то современные редакторы умеют отображать такой текст как надо.